# git merge vs rebase on a shared feature-branch

Tags: git, merge, branch, rebase

While working alone, I always rebase my feature-branch above master to be up to date.
However, when working on a feature-branch with multiple people this becomes an issue.
I had to force push a couple of times, and synchronize with others on that operation - since rebase operation changes history and creates non-fast forward condition when other people push their changes to that branch as well.

In such cases isn't it better to get updates from master using a merge instead of a rebase?

Comment: If you have a number of people working on a branch? Sure, rebasing is possinle but (as you are saying) too painful so merging is the way to go.

Comment: I didn't get how your team screwed this up. Every developer does `git pull --rebase origin master` immediately before sending a PR. This way it minimizes collision and keeps history clean.